# What is the terminal width by COLUMNS?

Tags: gnome-terminal

in `man bash`, I saw the environment variable `COLUMNS` is the terminal width.
I played with its different values, but it doesn't seem to be the actual terminal width in terms of number of characters:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mozilla
ii  rhythmbox-mozilla                      2.96-0ubuntu4.3                         Rhythmbox Mozilla plugin
ii  totem-mozilla                          3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1                       Totem Mozilla plugin
$ echo $COLUMNS
135
$ COLUMNS=13 dpkg -l | grep mozilla
ii  totem-mozilla  3.0.1-0ubuntu2 Totem Mozilla plugin
$ COLUMNS=1 dpkg -l | grep mozilla
ii  totem-mozilla  3.0.1-0ubuntu2 Totem Mozilla plugin
$ COLUMNS=100 dpkg -l | grep mozilla
ii  rhythmbox-mozilla   2.96-0ubuntu4.3     Rhythmbox Mozilla plugin
ii  totem-mozilla       3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1   Totem Mozilla plugin
$ COLUMNS=200 dpkg -l | grep mozilla
ii  rhythmbox-mozilla                            2.96-0ubuntu4.3                              Rhythmbox Mozilla plugin
ii  totem-mozilla                                3.0.1-0ubuntu21.1                            Totem Mozilla plugin
```

What is the terminal width by COLUMNS? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`COLUMNS` is a variable set by bash, and is not meant to be a variable you set manually. It's also not exported by default, so applications launched by the shell don't even see it.

What is it for then? It contains your terminal emulator's width in characters. It's vertical equivalent is `LINES`. They are both used by the `select` shell built-in. The `select` built-in is used for presenting the user with a list of items they can select. It then tries to display the list such that it fits within the terminal. Examples below:

With a 35x50 terminal window:

```
$ select foo in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do echo foo="$foo"; done
1) a    7) g  13) m  19) s  25) y
2) b    8) h  14) n  20) t  26) z
3) c    9) i  15) o  21) u
4) d   10) j  16) p  22) v
5) e   11) k  17) q  23) w
6) f   12) l  18) r  24) x
#?
```

With a 100x10 terminal window:

```
$ select foo in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do echo foo="$foo"; done
1) a    3) c   5) e   7) g   9) i  11) k  13) m  15) o  17) q  19) s  21) u  23) w  25) y
2) b    4) d   6) f   8) h  10) j  12) l  14) n  16) p  18) r  20) t  22) v  24) x  26) z
#?
```

Comment: `man` uses `$PAGER` (or `less` if unset). `$COLUMNS` isn't exported by the shell, meaning programs can't use it, because they don't have access to it.

Comment: Thank you for checking about `man`. I was talking about MANWIDTH. But as you explain it's about the underlying terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`$COLUMNS` gives the terminal width. Concerning the use with `dpkg -l`, you should look at the longest line (i.e. do not use `grep` as it will probably discard this line). And of course, if `$COLUMNS` is too small, such as 1 or 13, one can do nothing for you.

EDIT: if the `dpkg -l` output is not connected to a terminal, e.g. when piping to grep, dpkg uses column sizes based on the longest fields; thus the output may be wider than the terminal. If you want to take the terminal width into account, use:

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS dpkg -l | grep ...
```

Note that the shell variable `$COLUMNS` is not exported by default (i.e. not an environment variable), and `COLUMNS=$COLUMNS` has the effect to provide `COLUMNS` as an environment variable for dpkg.

Comment: thanks. If not using grep, how can I find out packages related to "mozilla", without discarding the longest line?

Comment: What I meant is that `dpkg -l` chooses the layout based on the longest line. But if you grep the output, the only sensible contexts are `$COLUMNS` undefined in the environment (the default) and `$COLUMNS` set to the terminal width (I've just edited my answer on this point).